# Number of solutions for x^2=a(mod m)

Tags: number-theory

I'm trying to understand how to know the numbers of solutions for x^2=a(mod m). I know that if a has roots they are solutions but how could I know the rest of them?
Is there a need to use the Chinese reminder here? if so how?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2152453/number-of-solutions-to-x2-equiv-a-pmod-m).

Comment: The chinese reminder theorem allows you to reduce the problem when $m$ is a prime power, since a solution of $x^2=a\bmod m$ is in correspondence with the system of equations $x^2=a\bmod p_j^{k_j}$ where $m=p_1^{j_1}\dots {p_r}^{j_r}$

Comment: Thanks. I think I got how to do it with Chinese reminder. I posted an answer and will be glad of someone could confirm if it is the right way to do it.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For typesetting, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it: I dismantle m to coprime numbers and check when the x^2=a(mod m) have solutions for each. lets say x^2=11^2(mod 1800) so it has solutions if and only if

x^2=11^2(mod 9)=4(mod 9)

x^2=11^2(mod 8)=1(mod 8)

x^2=11^2(mod 25)=21(mod 25)

Because 1800=9*8*25

x=+-2(mod 9)

x=+-1,+-3(mod 8)

x=+-11(mod 25)

so it has 2*4*2=16 solutions, is it right?

Comment: You are right. forgot I need to check numbers modulo. I edited it. is it right now?

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to know whether there are solutions: that's where the Legendre symbol comes in; there is a solution to $x^2\equiv a$ mod $m$ iff $\left(\frac{a}{m}\right)=1$. How to compute this Legendre symbol? Well, there are some fine tricks, one of them being the law of quadratic reciprocity.

After finding out it has a solution, one can find solutions the hard way by trying all numbers $1,2,3,\ldots,\lceil m\rceil$. Note that you don't have to checke the other half since if $a$ mod $m$ is a solution, then also $a-m$ mod $m$ is a solution.

There are more methods for finding the solutions but it all comes down to first checking the existence of a solution. For finding all solutions with less work, one can use **Tonelli's algorithm**, but you need to know about Legendre symbols and Jacobi symbols first.

You may find this post interesting: 
[Number of solutions to $x^2\equiv a\pmod m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2152453/number-of-solutions-to-x2-equiv-a-pmod-m?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of this but is works only if m is odd(at least I only learned Legendre symbol where m is odd). I asked this question because I got stuck on  where m is even

Comment: @IdanDaniel Jacobi symbols are the extension of Legendre symbols and they deal with the cases where $m$ is not prime.

Comment: I know. My professor only defined it for odd numbers though.

Comment: @IdanDaniel I should have looked better, but indeed it is defined for positive odd numbers only.

Comment: Note also that for Jacobi symbols, $\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)=-1$ tells you that $a$ is not a square modulo $b$, but if it is equal to $1$, it is still possible for $a$ to also not be a square modulo $b$. For example, that happens with $-1$ modulo $77$.